# How to check for a value in each iteration of a list

Tags: c#

I have a object that has a property which I need to check. I should be only able to set a flag as false ONLY when all items in the list for that property has met a specific condition.

```
foreach (Rows row in Result.Rows)
{
    if (row.Number <= 0)
    {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

As you see, currently if it finds a list itm has a row number <=0, it sets the value of flag as false.  But I want to check all Rows in the list and ONLY set as false when all rows's row number is false.

Comment: Rather than clarifying your question in an answer to your question, you can edit the original question.  I don't understand your question.  You say _when all rows's row number is false_.  However, it appears from your code that `row.Number` is an integer.  Integers are not true/false, they are numbers.  Did you look at @AlexKeySmith's answer.  I suspect that that answer (or some variation of that answer - again, I can't figure out what you are asking), is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
if(Result.Rows.All(x => x.Number <= 0))
{
    flag = false;
}
```

Here's some further docs on the All method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: That is likely true, but the question asks to check for "only set as false when _all_ rows's row number... ". However the question text is contrary to the code example in the question, so it is tricky to tell the original intent. Either way, All or Any is likely to solve the problem cleanly.

Comment: I am sort of convinced with your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-LINQ solution. You just need to reverse the logic and default to `false`.

```
var flag = false;
foreach (Rows row in Result.Rows)
{
    if (row.Number > 0)
    {
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result pretty quickly with the `All` extension for LINQ.

```
flag = !Result.Rows.All(x => x.Number <= 0);
```

I am assuming that when you say 'only set as false when' you mean that it should only be false if all rows' Number property is <= 0, not that assignment should be skipped entirely.

Comment: Or `flag = !Result.Rows.Any(x => x.Number > 0);`. It returns earlier (possibly).

Comment: @Jimi All and Any both have opportunities to exit early.

Comment: It's the LINQ version of @John Wu' answer. You can keep it. I don't think a downvote here is required. -- `All()` needs to verify, well, *all*.

Comment: @Jimi Not quite. All needs to return true when all elements hold to the predicate. As soon as one does not, it can return false, as all elements do not satisfy the condition. `!All(x => x) == Any(x => !x)`, and vice-versa, essentially.